# Webservice Client and Compression

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, iis-7, asmx

I have Managed to Setup II7 with Gzip Compression .

I can check via web sniffer that my asmx web service encoding is Gzip but how to i enable 
gzip Compression on my C# Client , i am using the Web Service is Service reference in my application.

Actually i am trying to send large amount of data , 10k objects of array so Compression with be great effect on bw.

**but how do I enable Compression on my C# Client.**

i am trying to see that many people sees same problem but there nothing clear answer some says use third party tools or some says about custom headers etc etc .

is not there any proper way  , built in to consume Compressed web service

Comment: No One ! :( , after founding no answer ,  i had tried to my complete objects to json and then again json to object in my client , but this doesnt make any major diffrence ,

Comment: A quick search leads me to believe you may need to create a custom encoder. There really is a _lot_ of stuff about this out there. Even [Scott Hanselman has an article about it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As @Igby Largeman pointed out, you can use your `IIS7` to enable the compression on the server, but this is not enough.
The main idea is to set the headers on the client side **and** server side:

**Client**:

```
Accept-Encoding = "gzip, deflate";
```

You can achieve this by code:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://foofoo");
request.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
```

or

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://foofoo");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |  
  DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

If you use some WCF client, and not the `HttpWebRequest`, you should use custom inspector and dispatcher, like in [this article](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/ramon/archive/2008/11/06/wcf-and-http-gzip-deflate-compression-and-silverlight.aspx):

> So I used a message inspector implementing `IClientMessageInspector` and `IDispatchMessageInspector` to automatically set the `AcceptEncoding` and `ContentEncoding` http headers.
>
> This was working perfectly but I could not achieve to decompress the response on the server by first detecting the `ContentEncoding` header thus I used the work around to first try to decompress it and if it fails just try to process the request as normal.
>
> I also did this in the client pipeline and this also works.

**Server**:

```
// This is the nearly same thing after all
Content-Encoding = "gzip" OR Content-Encoding = "deflate"
```

To do this on the Server side, you should enable httpCompression in the IIS.
I think you should check the [original article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx) to get this work